# how to edit textview in fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, textview

**SOLVED**

I would like to set new text to `TextView`. I have new value of `TextView` in `MainActivity` but this activity doesn't know this `TextView`. `TextView` is in the file `fragment_main.xml`. Fragment class is included in `MainActivity.java` file like inner static class. It was default generated activity with fragment in Eclipse. Can you help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ... 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment() { } 

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.zonemedia.skener.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/viewmoje"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.zonemedia.skener.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texturl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_url" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 1:**
I tried to make public method (=setter) in Fragment and call it from FragmentActivity. 
I also tried to change text directly from fragment: 
       `TextView textUrl = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.texturl);
       textCode.setText("random");`

I tried what @masmic_87 wrote. In fragment I defined 
`TextView fragmentTextView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.texturl);`

and then in the activity I putted your code. App is still crashing:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.....MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException caused by line 86: ((PlaceholderFragment) fragment).fragmentTextView.setText("something");`

Last I tried call static String directly from static fragment but MainActivity.this is underline with reason: The static field MainActivity.this should be accessed in a static way and No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope.

I also tried moved inner class PlaceholderFragment to new .java file and now it is not static. I tried all recommendations from here and nothing is working

**SOLVED** 
I dont know where I had my head. In fragment I called (TextView) **getView()**.... instead of

```
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
   mTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.texturl);
   mTextView.setText("new text");
```

Comment: What have you alread ytried?

Comment: You should have a reference to your fragment in you activity.

Comment: I tried to make public method (=setter) in Fragment and call it from FragmentActivity. I also tried to change text directly from fragment:
`TextView textUrl = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.texturl);    
textCode.setText("random");`

Comment: @Brano_SR Please edit your question with that code so that you can format it correctly. This will make it much easier for others to read.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look if this works for you.

Make reference to your fragment in the activity:

```
PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
```

Then define the text you want on your fragment's textview:

```
((PlaceholderFragment)fragment).fragmentTextView.setText(text you want);
```

This would be to pass the textview's value to the fragment in any moment. If you want to pass this value at the moment you call the fragment transaction, it would be better to do it this way:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("textview", "new_value");
PlaceholderFragment fragment= new PlaceholderFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
transaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. In fragment I defined `TextView fragmentTextView = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.texturl);` and then in the activity I putted your code. App still crashing: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.....MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`
caused by line 86: `((PlaceholderFragment) fragment).fragmentTextView.setText("something");`

Answer (score 1):

if the fragment is a static innner class of the activity, then why don't you just store the text in a static string in the activity and then the fragment will have direct access to it through MainActivity.this.stringName.

This solution will make you code pretty highly coupled but if its a static inner class and they have to pass data around like this anyway, then you don't really have to worry about that.

Comment: It doesn't work. MainActivity.this is underline with reason: The static field MainActivity.this should be accessed in a static way and No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope.
I also tried moved inner class to new .java file and now it is not static. I tried all recommendations from here and nothing is working.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the **onCreate()**. You can use a binding to **setContentView()**.

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = 
ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());

textviewname = findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
textviewname.setText("some text");
```

Comment: wow, you are on good track to find end of internet (by responding to my 8y old question) :D but anyway thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31268595)